# Input devices connected by cable are randomly freezing

Tags: keyboard, catalina, usb, mouse, performance

I got a MacBook Pro 2020 with the lates MacOS installed.
I generally use it with 2 Monitors and a Mouse and Keyboard connected via USB-C Kabel, or Dongle (Happens for both options). I can use everything without problems for a certain amount of time (10min- 5h). Suddenly all my input devices connected via cable freeze and I can't use them without rebooting. The lights of the keyboard and mouse are still on, so i guess the usb port is still powered. Everything else (Monitor, Bluetooth Keyboard (used for reference), Headset) keeps working perfectly fine. After rebooting the Mac, everything is working fine again.
This behavior is rather annoying when I'm working. For reference: My MacBook is closed and connected via USB-C to the charger and the Monitors.

Comment: It's probably your USB hub, given that what you described is your USB devices locking up, but your video is working fine.

Comment: But it's happening even without usb hub. When I connect my keyboard via usb-c directly into the MacBook it happens too.

Comment: that's worse..it could be the USB controller in your MacBook Pro.  Try booting in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting) to ensure you're not loading any 3rd party drivers/software.  If it keeps happening, it's either a macOS or Apple issue.  But let's start there and see what we get.